# React/Material UI - Change react resetOnSubmit value dynamically

Tags: meteor, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using meteor-react-form-handler (made by coniel). I have added the 'resetOnSubmit={false}' prop to the  tag, but I'm trying to get the my form to ONLY reset after passing my validations. Is there any way to change that value to true if the form is correct and has no validation issues?

```
<Form schema={addKittenFormSchema} id="addKittenForm" onSubmit={this._addKitten} resetOnSubmit={false}>
```

I have tried using the this.refs.form.reset() which is found inside Form.jsx from the package, but it doesn't seem to reset the form after I submit it.

This is code I found when I inspected the package:

```
if (this.props.resetOnSubmit !== false) {
            this.refs.form.reset();
}
```

Is there a way to manually call the reset outside of the scope of the Material-UI component?